# Android recyclerview with offseted recycling

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to modify horizontal recycler view to not destroy next item right away, it can be destroyed i.e after 10 layouts.

Basically I'm trying to expand viewport(visible) items that are held in recycler, so if 10 are visible, `I want to have 30 items to be ready so recycler doesn't destroy them right after they exit viewport`. I know that maybe it will have some performance issues, but that doesn't matter at the time.

**Is that even possible and how can I achieve that?**

Comment: What is your motivation? To be correct, items are not destroyed when they leave viewport, but `recycled`. I guess you don't want them to be recycled either.

Comment: @skywall yeah, that's what I meant. Sorry for sloppy language. I don't want them to recycler either, I have horizontal list and element from prevoius (i+1) item that overlaps with  item (i). When I scroll to the right , element (i+1) is hidden so that overlapped view  also disapears and I don't want that. I want that view to stay, and i.e after 10 items changed to disapear with some offset.

Comment: You can maybe solve this with "precaching" views in RecyclerView. Take a look at method [`getExtraLayoutSpace()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/LinearLayoutManager.html#getExtraLayoutSpace(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.State)) of LinearLayoutManager

Comment: @skywall I'm already using it as in this example: https://github.com/williamrobertson13/Samahope/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/samahop/samahope/widgets/PreCachingLayoutManager.java

No luck with this issue.